# Support Vector Regression applied to time series with lagged predictors

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, svm, autoregressive, lags

I am relatively new to time series. I am dealing with an energy consumption prediction problem. Data points are sampled on a 15-minutes frequency. I have a set of exogenous variables such as temeperature and other calendar variables.

Due to the multiple seasonalities present in my dataset I have preferred, at a first instance, SVR over autoregressive models.

Now the question. I have included the t-1 lagged dependent variable among my predictors (consumptions measured 15 minutes before ahead). According to some evidence and other answers I have come across here, it shouldn't be an issue if the problem is predictive and not explanatory (as in my case). My question is: is this approach also correct when considering models such as SVR (with Gaussian kernel) which are not linear regression or based on OLS? Secondly: what about using the lagged variable as a predictor also in autoregressive models such as ARIMA or SARIMA? I think it may be an issue in this case because the autoregressive component of these models already takes into account the correlation between the dependent variable and its observation at t-1, t-2, t-n...but I would like to know more about that.

It would be greate if you could provide some reference to deepen your explanation!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For predictive purposes you may use however the series should be stationary, or you should make it stationary before applying SVR. Otherwise the training data of the past will have no value for future prediction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cagdas Ozgenc. Yes, the series is stationary. Do you think this is the only prerequisite to use lagged DV in SVR models? Thanks again.

Comment: And second question: do you think that this may be true also for autoregressive models?